# Does each SSIS job run under it's own AppDomain?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm creating a custom SSIS job that has an execute script task. I need to reference some third party dlls that I do not have the source code for within this script task. I would like to avoid installing these dlls in the GAC since I would worry about Dll hell in case different versions of the ssis jobs need different versions of similar assemblies. I have seen that you can resolve assemblies dynamically using the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve method. I think this would work well assuming that as long as SSIS jobs don't share AppDomains.

Is there any documentation of the standard execution order of SSIS jobs that are hosted on sql server clusters? Does a new process get spun up per job execution or do they share process space and spin up a new app domain? Do they all run under the same process and app domain?

Answer (score 0):

> Does a new process get spun up per job execution

Yes.  SSIS packages tend to load 3rd party unmanaged drivers (OleDB, ODBC) of varying quality, and so process isolation is required enable SSIS to run multiple different packages reliably.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I would hope so. Do you know of any documentation? I'm trying to convince my coworkers this strategy is safe.

Comment: Using the SSIS Catalog or not?

Comment: Sorry for the delay I had to ask around. Yes the SSIS jobs are installed in the SSIS Catalog